# Font Issues: HTML field types "text" and "textarea" are displaying different fonts

Tags: html, css, text, textarea

Text in my pages' HTML field types "text" and "textarea" show different fonts...Is this just the nature of the different fields?

I have tried specifying the font type within the background CSS file and within the HTML. No luck.

Full disclosure...novice at work.

Comment: And what are the css declarations for these objects?

Comment: just changed them to according to Ahmed's comment...

Answer (score 3):

you can change their fonts by:

```
textarea {
    font-family: "Tahoma", "Arial", "Arabic Transparent";
}
input[type=text] {
    font-family: "Tahoma", "Arial";
}
```

This way is working with me very good, but you should write fonts that usually found in your visitor's PC.

Comment: Thanks. This helped. I will do some browser testing and see if the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

```
textarea, input { font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/gakfk/

Make sure that the `input` and `textarea` have the same font family and font size.

Also, you may want to use classes to differentiate different types of input field, say text and submit.

Comment: The link was helpful. Thanks!